# React Native 'Webview' not loading scripts in production build -iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, webview, react-native-webview

I have html file with scripts, I need to display it in `React native` screen so I used `react-native-webview`, it is working fine in `ios` debug build but not working in `ios` production build getting blank screen

This is my html page

```
<html >
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<body onload="loader();">

<script>
    window.fwSettings = {
        'widget_id': 7300********
    };
    !function () { 
        if ("function" != typeof window.FreshworksWidget)
         { 
             var n = function () {
                  n.q.push(arguments) 
                }; 
                n.q = [],
                 window.FreshworksWidget = n } }() 
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' 
   src='https://widget.freshworks.com/widgets/7*********.js' async defer></script>

<script>
    function loader() {
        FreshworksWidget('hide', 'launcher');
        FreshworksWidget('open');
    };
 </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I placed this html page in `Webview` like this

```
<WebView
      source={kbHTML}
      javaScriptEnabled={true}
      domStorageEnabled={true}
      originWhitelist={['*']}
      scalesPageToFit={false}
      startInLoadingState={true}
      automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
      containerStyle={{
        flex: 1,
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%'
      }}
    
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        height: height,
        width: width,
        resizeMode: 'cover',
      }}

    />
```

its working fine in `ios` debug mode but not working in `ios` production build.getting blank screen.

> react-native-webview: "^11.18.1",
> react-native: "0.64.2"

Comment: Did you make it work? I am facing the same issue ?

Comment: facing same issue, please provide solution